# List of dates with summarizing hours

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to create a list of dates, which summarize the first three hours and then the next three. Something like:
`['2016/05/01-00-02h', '2016/05/01-03-05h', '2016/05/01-06-08h',.....'2016/05/31-21-23h']`. Until now, I have only a list of dates without the summary.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta

deb = '20160501'
fin = '20160531'

start = dt.strptime(deb, "%Y%m%d")
end = dt.strptime(fin, "%Y%m%d") + timedelta(days=1)

def hour_range(start, end):
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start += timedelta(hours=1)

date_list = [h.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H') for h in hour_range(start, end)]
```

Comment: you can't have such sequence `31-21-23h`, according to your logic it should be `31-22-24h` or `31-22-00h`

Comment: why? 31 should be the last day of May and the hours are 21-23h. 00:00 should be again the next day, like '2016/06/01 00-02h'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you need using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('2016-05-01', '2016-06-01', freq='2h')

result = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(dates, closed='left').tolist()
#[Interval('2016-05-01', '2016-05-01 02:00:00', closed='left'),
#Interval('2016-05-01 02:00:00', '2016-05-01 04:00:00', closed='left'),
#Interval('2016-05-01 04:00:00', '2016-05-01 06:00:00', closed='left')
#...
#'2016-05-31 20:00:00', closed='left'),
#Interval('2016-05-31 20:00:00', '2016-05-31 22:00:00', closed='left'),
#Interval('2016-05-31 22:00:00', '2016-06-01', closed='left')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, it is not really what i want. I want to use the list for my x-axis in my plot. So, i need the date and the range 00:00 - 02:00h in the way which i mentioned above. And the range should go on with 03:00 - 05:00h and then 06:00-08:00h.......

Answer (score 0):

Treat it as arithmetic. Set your start time to 2am, then increment it by `timedelta(hours=3)` until you have produced all desired time points. (Given the interval, there are 8 time points before you roll over to the next day.) For example:

```
start += timedelta(hours=2)   # Advance to 2am
while start < end:
    yield start
    start += timedelta(hours=3)
```